# Selenium Remote Web Driver: How to start the remote server from Client

Tags: python, selenium-rc, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have few questions in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium2) :

My 1st question is, do I need a standalone .jar file for RemoteWebDriver?
My 2nd question is, if the standalone .jar file is needed, then how can I start this .jar file/Selenium Server from the WebDriver's Client side (just like in Selenium RC) using Python ?

I do know how to start the selenium server from command line locally. But I was wondering if WebDriver has any improvements from RC regarding starting the Server. I am also aware that there is no need of a Selenium Server (standalone .jar file) if WebDriver is used locally.

Comment: [The Selenium Server – When to Use It](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#the-selenium-server-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes standalone jar file need to be in running state, in order to run tests on remote machine using `RemoteWebDriver`.
2. To run the server, just use `java -jar` that probably you know already.

refer: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver for more details.